# Spservices autocomplete with many columns

Tags: column, spservices

Could somebody advise how can I make autocomplete for multiple columns, currently I'm using it for one column:

```
$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "My list",
    sourceColumn: "Email",
    columnName: "user1",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 1000,
    debug: true
});
```

Can I do something like this:

```
...
columnName: "user1", "user2", "user3"... etc.
...
```

UPDATE:

My form and JavaScript looks like this:

```
<div class="tr">
  <div class="td">
    <input title="user1" data-bind="textInput: user1Email, valueUpdate:'blur'" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <div class="td">
    <input title="user2" data-bind="textInput: user2Email, valueUpdate:'blur'" />
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(["user1", "user2", "user3"]).each(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "User List",
            sourceColumn: "Email",
            columnName: this,
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 3,
            slideDownSpeed: 1000,
            debug: true
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call SPAutocomplete separately for each column.

```
$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "My list",
    sourceColumn: "Email",
    columnName: "user1",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 1000,
    debug: true
});

$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "My list",
    sourceColumn: "Email",
    columnName: "user2",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 1000,
    debug: true
});

$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "My list",
    sourceColumn: "Email",
    columnName: "user3",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 1000,
    debug: true
});
```

### Update

Here is is in a loop:

```
$(["user1", "user2", "user3"]).each(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
        sourceList: "My list",
        sourceColumn: "Email",
        columnName: this,
        ignoreCase: true,
        numChars: 3,
        slideDownSpeed: 1000,
        debug: true
    });
})
```

### Update 2

Thanks for posting the HTML. Here is the function that SPervices uses to find the correct fields:

> ```
> function findFormField(columnName) {
>     var thisFormBody;
>     // There's no easy way to find one of these columns; we'll look for the comment with the columnName
>     var searchText = RegExp("FieldName=\"" + columnName.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&") + "\"", "gi");
>     // Loop through all of the ms-formbody table cells
>     $("td.ms-formbody, td.ms-formbodysurvey").each(function () {
>         // Check for the right comment
>         if (searchText.test($(this).html())) {
>             thisFormBody = $(this);
>             // Found it, so we're done
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
>     return thisFormBody;
> } // End of function findFormField
> ```

You would have to change your fields in a way that they can be found by that function. The important part here would be the FieldName-attribute that SPServices is looking for.

### Update 3:

Here is the minimal HTML you will need:

```
<tr>
    <td class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="user1" -->
        <input title="user1" /> 
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="user2" -->
        <input title="user2" /> 
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="user3" -->
        <input title="user3" /> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

For that to work you will also need columns in your list that have exactly the same display name as your field titles. So in the above example your list has to have at least the 3 columns with display name *user1*, *user2*, *user3*.

And you have to make sure that the original SP form fields are NOT on the form where you run the SPServices.SPAutocomplete-function.

Comment: I have more than 20 columns, I know this approach will work, but I'm looking for more elegant solution...

Comment: Please see my update. Is that more elegant enough?

Comment: It works thanks, but with little issue. Drop down menu appears only for a column. E.g: I have 10 columns, when I type first 3 chars in column #10, drop down appears from column #1. =)

Comment: Please post the HTML content of the table containing all the form elements.

Comment: I see, your fields are not SharePoint fields. SPServices is looking for fields that comply with SharePoint specifications and not with Knockout.

Comment: Yes it's custom html form with knockout binding. Not sure will your function above apply?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: @DanielStölzner
I've tried your script with the loop with the Title column cause we want to use the function in more than one language. I replaced the  **$(["user1", "user2", "user3"]).each(function(){** with **$(["Title", "Titel"]).each(function(){** but it doesn't work. Is there anything else to do?